# How to submit a JCL through SQR Call System Command on MVS z/os?

Tags: zos, peoplesoft, jcl, sqr, mvs

I’m trying to submit a JCL through an SQR Program using Call System Command on MVS z/os. The JCL resides in specific Dataset.

What I’m trying do is something like this:

1. let $jclcmd= 'SUBMIT PSLIBDSN.O92.CUST7.JCLSRC(UTILI)'
2. call system using $jclcmd #rtnstat

Up to this point, I have not been able to submit the JCL. What I get from the mainframe is this error: 
**** WARNING **** ERRNO = ESYS
Generated in   SYSTEM called from line    389 of      SYS(UCALL)  , offset 000118
Program SUBMIT   was abnormally terminated with a system code of 66D.SYS(UCALL)  , offset 000118

I also tried let $jclcmd= 'TSO SUBMIT PSLIBDSN.O92.CUST7.JCLSRC(UTILI)' but gets this: 
Program TSO      was abnormally terminated with a system code of 806.
SYSTEM COMPLETION CODE=806 REASON CODE=00000004

Up to this point I have thought that the call system function does not allow operating system commands to be executed for reasons of incompatibility with MVS. The reality is that the SQR documentation does not mention that it is not, but always mentions Windows and UNIX as an example. I have made a thousand attempts to execute a REXX program, submit a JCL and others but looks like the function is not right assembling the command. 
Any idea will be welcome.

Comment: Can you post the entire message ?    Abend 66D should be accompanied by a reason code as documented here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ieah700/m015231.htm

Comment: This is exactly what I get:  **** WARNING **** ERRNO = ESYS Generated in SYSTEM called from line 389 of SYS(UCALL) , offset 000118 Program SUBMIT was abnormally terminated with a system code of 66D.SYS(UCALL) , offset 000118

Comment: It sounds like the SQR runtime environment is being "helpful" in not giving you the actual S66D error message.  Can you see anything related in the output of your TSO session in SDSF (provided your shop uses SDSF)?  That would be the job with your userID as the name and a job type of TSU.

Comment: Not all. It's as if the Submit keyword were interpreting it as a program name and would like to execute "Submit" instead of submitting the JCl with the DSN given. SYSTEM COMPLETION CODE=66D  REASON CODE=00000008

Comment: That would be a S806 abend (program not found).  According to the helpful link @Hogstrom posted, S66D with reason code 8 indicates "An abend X'0C4' occurred when validating user pointers or a pointer was set to zero."  You might want to talk to your system's administrators.